# Unique Values per row in Pandas groupby

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a simple `dataframe` (df) like shown below:

```
index Job  Person 
1     j1   Cathy
2     j2   Mark
3     j3   Cathy
4     j4   Steve
5     j5   Cathy
6          Cathy
7     j1   Cathy
```

I would like to convert the above `dataframe` as:

```
Person CountJob  JobDetails
Cathy     4      j1;j3;j5
Mark      1      j2
Steve     1      j4
```

i.e, drop the **Nulls** and join **Unique** jobs for each person.

I can partially solve this using `groupby` :

```
df.groupby('Person').agg(CountJob=('Job','count'),
                         JobDetails=('Job',lambda x: ';'.join(x.dropna()))
                        )
```

I am able to drop null values but can't seem to get unique values; in the above example, for '***Cathy***', '***JobDetails***' becomes `j1;j3;j5;j1`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding `unique` chain with `dropna`

```
df.groupby('Person').agg(CountJob=('Job','count'),
                         JobDetails=('Job',lambda x: ';'.join(x.dropna().unique()))
                        )
Out[143]: 
        CountJob JobDetails
Person                     
Cathy          4   j1;j3;j5
Mark           1         j2
Steve          1         j4
```

Comment: aah. I was setting the .unique() after the join()..Hence, it kept failing.. thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

You could consider dropping the null before aggregating:

```
   (
    df.dropna()
    .groupby("Person")
    .agg(CountJob=("Job", "count"), JobDetails=("Job", set))
    .assign(JobDetails=lambda df: df.JobDetails.str.join(","))
)

      CountJob  JobDetails
Person      
Cathy   4   j1,j3,j5
Mark    1   j2
Steve   1   j4
```

Answer (score 1):

Another method would be to set the index as the `Person` and `stack` to drop any nulls, then we can apply any group by args without any issue.

```
df.set_index('Person').stack().groupby('Person')\
                .agg(JobDetails=('unique'), Job=('count'))

          JobDetails  Job
Person                   
Cathy   [j1, j3, j5]    4
Mark            [j2]    1
Steve           [j4]    1
```